React Native App with MongoDB Realm Sync Stays on Login Screen
I've developed a React Native app that utilizes MongoDB Realm Sync. This setup allows users to perform operations locally when offline, with changes syncing to a live MongoDB Atlas database once the internet is restored. Additionally, the app has a dedicated Node.js backend employing JWT for authentication.
Issue: Despite successful connections to the backend (verified by JWT usage and Realm connections), the app does not transition from the login screen to the dashboard after login.
Environment:
React Native
MongoDB Realm Sync
Node.js backend with JWT authentication
Code is given below for reference.
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { AppProvider, UserProvider, RealmProvider } from '@realm/react';
import { ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { RealmQuickSale, RealmProduct } from '../modal/sales';
import Config from '../../atlasConfig.json';
import AppNavigator from '../navigation/AppNavigator';
import LoginScreen from './components/LoginScreen';

const RealmScreen = () => {
const LoadingIndicator = () => {
console.log('===== Falling Back to LoadingIndicator');
return (
  <View style={styles.activityContainer}>
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
  </View>
);

};
return (
  <AppProvider id={Config.appId} baseUrl={Config.baseUrl}>
  <UserProvider fallback={LoginScreen}>
    <RealmProvider
      schema={[RealmQuickSale, RealmProduct]}
      sync={{
        flexible: true,
        onError: (_session, error) => {
          console.error(error); // Log sync errors
        },
      }}
      fallback={LoadingIndicator}>
      <AppNavigator />
    </RealmProvider>
  </UserProvider>
</AppProvider>
);

};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
activityContainer: {
flex: 1,
flexDirection: 'row',
justifyContent: 'space-around',
padding: 10,
},
});
export default RealmScreen;

Did you do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected? If so, what line presented unexpected results? If not, please do that an update the question with more details so we know where to look. Also, please be sure to format code using the formatting tools {} in the question so it's readable.
